# How to go about implementing a fast shortest path search for a 1-crate sokoban?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, shortest-path, path-finding

In one of my university courses (in Data-structures and Algorithmics), we are given a bonus assignment based on the game Sokoban:

[image: Sokoban GIF]

With one Major exception: We only have one crate to push to our goal.

> **Example input**
>
> ```
> 8 8
> MMMMMMMM
> M.....?M
> M....TTM
> M....TTM
> M..!...M
> M....+.M
> M......M
> MMMMMMMM
> ```

Here the first line gives the dimensions (`b x h`) of the board (8 by 8 in this case). This is followed up by `h` lines oh `b` characters. The meaning of these characters is as follows: `.` A walkable space, `?` the goal (red point in the gif), `!` the crate, and `+` is our position.

We are asked to output the shortest solution to the puzzle. (Note that a puzzle might be unsolveable.) We output this in 2 lines, the first tells us how many moves, and the second tells us the correct path. For the example, this would be:

> **Example Output**
>
> ```
> 10
> WWNNNWNEEE
> ```

Now, finding an algorithm that works isn't really an issue. Seeing as we're looking for the shortest path, and the nodes on this specific graph are in essence unweighted, I've implemented a breadth first search. In broad strokes, my current implementation looks like this:

```
0. Since the maze doesn't change, describe each state as a whole number based on the coordinates 
     of the crate and the player. - This defines a state uniquely and reduces memory costs.
1. Create a dictionary of visited states.
2. Get the input positions of the goal, crate and player.
3. Set up a Queue of move sequences.
4. Pop a move sequence from the Queue.
5. If this move sequence wins the game, go to step 8.
6. Make new move sequences which are copies of the original, each with a different legal move appended.
7. Append these new move sequences to the Queue.
8. Go to step 4
9. Print the output.
```

This is, of course a relatively simple algorithm. The problem is that it isn't fast enough. In one of the final test cases, we're thrown a `196 x 22` maze like "level" which has a solution that takes 2300 steps. We're asked to solve this level within 10 seconds, but it takes my algorithm more than 10 minutes.

Because of that, I'm kinda at a loss. I've already managed to increase the algorithm's speed 10 fold, and I still have 2 orders of magnitude to go...

Hence why I'm asking here: What makes this algorithm so slow, and how can I speed it up?

Comment: Well, it is probably implementation that has a problem, not algorithm. But without any code nobody can help you here. 10 minutes on a modern hardware is a lot of computations. Something somewhere is very wrong

Comment: @trailmax I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the code. I've asked the professor about this. Would it be best to delete this question until I've got an answer to that?

Comment: I've always been a fan of [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: @itsme86 With A* being an expansion on Dijkstra's algorithm, is it not nearly equivalent to BFS in a non-weighted graph? Especially since the distance function would be quite hard to calculate in this case.

Comment: Not that hard. Distance function is the Manhattan distance between the crate and the goal, plus the number of moves. Add also Manhattan distance between the crate and the player, but with smaller coefficient than the previous two.

Comment: The number of moves is the most important metric, then the distance between the goal and the crate, and then the distance between the crate and the player. Give them some coefficients, experiment a bit, and see what happens.

Comment: You could alternate the crate moves and player moves. A "crate move" is only possible when player is next to the crate, and there is empty space on the other side. The crate and the player move by one spot. A "player move" can lead the player only to the four available spots next to the crate, if there is an empty spot on the opposite side of the crate. And it can also be a "non-move", if player is next to the crate, and there is an empty spot opposite of it.

Comment: @MitchellFaas No, A\* and BFS are not (nearly) equivalent in an unweighted graph (unless you provide a trivial heuristic function). The heuristic function is what makes A\* different from BFS and reduces how much effort you spend on exploring what's clearly the wrong direction (the GIF on Wikipedia is an example of an unweighted graph).

Comment: do you have a link to the 196x22 maze ? you got me intrigued :-) very nicely and intelligently expressed question by the way !

Comment: @SamuelVidal  Sure! It turned out to be an issue with my implementation. I've since managed to fix that, and it now runs in 0.4 seconds; so I don't know how interesting it still is. Regardless, you can find it here: https://pastebin.com/KScKYE7W

Comment: well I would still be interested to play with the maze. Congrats for fixing your implementation.

Comment: @SamuelVidal It's in the edited version of my comment. You were so fast in responding though, that I'm not sure whether you saw it; so here's a second message :')

Comment: Cheers mate ! really cool maze indeed :-)

Comment: 3 orders of magnitudes ! nice

Comment: Nice bit of trivia : according to wikipedia, general sokoban is [P-Space complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE-complete).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your comprehensive BFS search will be *slow*.  You spend a large amount of your tree search in moves that are utterly wasted, your player thrashing around the maze area to no avail.

Change the focus of your goal: first, solve the maze for the **crate** rather than sending the player every which way.  Include a heuristic for moving the crate closer to the goal spot.  Make sure that the crate moves are possible: that there is a "push from " spot available for each move.

One initial heuristic is to make a maze fill by raw distance to the goal start at either the goal (what I've done here) and increment the steps through the maze, or start at the box and increment from there.

```
MMMMMMMM
M54321?M
M6543TTM
M7654TTM    
M876567M   <== crate is on the farther 6
M987678M   <== player is on the nearer 7
Ma98789M
MMMMMMMM
```

Here, you would first try to find legal pushes to move the box along the path 654321?.  You can also update this by making a penalty (moving the player without pushing) for any direction change.

These heuristics will give you a very good upper bound for a solution; you can then retrace decision points to try other paths, always keeping your "shortest solution" for any position.

Also keep track of where you've been, so that you don't waste time in position loops: *never* repeat a move (position and direction).

Does that help you get going?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a pure dfs search of the player's movements, consider only the **crate** moves available to you at the time. For instance, in the very first frame of your gif, at the beginning of the simulation, the only crate move possible is the top one to the right one square.

An analogy would be for a game of chess on the first move, you would not consider any queen or bishop moves since they are all blocked by pawns.

After you've successfully found the sequence of crate moves leading to the solution, come back and trace the player moves necessary to construct the sequence of crate moves.

This improves time complexity because the time complexity will be based on the number of crates present in the map instead of total squares.

Comment: Finding the shortest path from a crate C to Goal T does not guarantee the shortest distance for person P. 

Take ▧ = Wall, P = Person, C = Crate, ▢ = Empty space :
Row 1: ▢ P▧▢G,
Row 2: ▢▢▢▢▢,
Row 3: ▢▧C▧▢,
Row 4: ▢▢▢▢▢,
Row 5: ▢▢▢▢▢